# how to select all with the same exact id and replace ONLY the id for a new random one?

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have:

```
<input type="text" id="first" attribute1="test" attribute2="hello" attribute3="happy">
<input type="text" id="first" attribute1="test" attribute2="hello" attribute3="happy">
<input type="text" id="first" attribute1="test" attribute2="hello" attribute3="happy">
```

it may be 2, 3 or more.

I want to select all input's that has id exactly "first" and then dinamically generantes new ids something like "first_3192391" "first_9592213" but it must be unique for each one, and then replace the "first" for this new one generated.

```
find("#first").each() {
   new_id = time.now();
   current_id = this.id
   this.replace(current_id, new_id)
}
```

something like the above algorithim should return:

```
<input type="text" id="first_32931" attribute1="test" attribute2="hello" attribute3="happy">
<input type="text" id="first_24122" attribute1="test" attribute2="hello" attribute3="happy">
<input type="text" id="first_31292" attribute1="test" attribute2="hello" attribute3="happy">
```

I was trying to use the replaceWith() method but with no luck.

Comment: Having multiple elements with the same ID is not valid. IDs have to be unique. You should fix this. Or this your attempt to fix it?

Comment: So you have no control over the generated HTML? How are these elements generated in the first place?

Comment: What exactly is auto-generating the html? I think you should try to fix it there, not in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give each html attribute a class, then select by the class, loop through them and then assign ids

```
 $(".first").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("id", Math.floor(Math.random()*1000));
    });
```

HTML:

```
 <input type="text" class="first" attribute1="test" attribute2="hello" attribute3="happy">
    <input type="text" class="first" attribute1="test" attribute2="hello" attribute3="happy">
    <input type="text" class="first" attribute1="test" attribute2="hello" attribute3="happy">
```

Comment: apparently he can't change the html, otherwise this would be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should setup your application so that it generates valid HTML. However, if this is not possible, you could do:

```
$('input[id="first"]').prop('id', function(i, id) {
   return  id + '_' + i;
});
```

This iterates over all input fields which have the id `first` and appends the index they have in the set to the id.

Comment: Doing this on the document.ready, how could I verify if the changes was correctly applied?

Comment: @KleberS.: Inspect the DOM with Firebug or Chrome dev tools etc.

Comment: It's a bit large, I looked on the outerHTML, is it the right place to look for the changes?

Comment: @KleberS.: You just have to right click on any of the input fields and select "Inspect Element" or similar.

Comment: @Kleber: Then your HTML is not as you posted it. It clearly works: http://jsfiddle.net/J9m38/1/ have a look at the output and inspect the fields... Or which jQuery version are you using? Maybe you have to use `attr` instead of `prop`.

Comment: King, actually the kmb385 posted code has worked but thanks for all help man!

Comment: @Kleber: If you are able to change the template so that it does not contain duplicate IDs, then you don't need to use jQuery at all. Or is there a reason that every of this element needs an ID?